# MassTransit and Broadcasting

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to get a messaging system up and running betwen multiple applications. I have an instance of RabbitMQ running and that appears to be fine. I can connect multiple subscribers/publisher to the RabbitMQ instance and they appear to be fine. I can then publish a message from one publisher but only one subscriber is getting the message.

I believe it has to do with the the way I am establishing the queues. I've looked at the tutorial on Rabbit, https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html, but I dont know hopw this translates into the Masstransit library.

For the life of me I am having trouble working out what I am doing wrong.

NuGets:

- MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.3.2
- MassTransit.RabbitMQ 5.3.2

Can anyone help?

```
        // Register MassTransit
        services.AddMassTransit(mtCfg =>
        {
            mtCfg.AddConsumer<DomainMessageConsumer>();

            mtCfg.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rbCfg =>
            {
                var host = rbCfg.Host(settings.RabbitMq.Host, settings.RabbitMq.VirtualHost, h =>
                {
                    h.Username(settings.RabbitMq.Username);
                    h.Password(settings.RabbitMq.Password);
                });

                rbCfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, settings.RabbitMq.ConnectionName, ep =>
                {
                    ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
                    ep.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));

                    ep.ConfigureConsumer<DomainMessageConsumer>(provider);
                });
            }));
        });
```

Comment: I suggest you start with reading the docs about MassTransit, not RMQ : http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/producing-messages.html#publishing-events and http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/troubleshooting/common-gotchas.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is because you are using the same queuename on all consumers. If you want broadcasting to all consumers, you should make all queuenames unique. In your code example, it's the `settings.RabbitMq.ConnectionName` variable that you should make unique for each consumer.

Check the below picture and imagine `Subscription B` is the queue `settings.RabbitMq.ConnectionName` you've set. What you'll get is the left part on the picture, only `Subscriber B1` receives (actually it's round-robin balancing, but this is going offtopic). If you want broadcasting, you can create separate subscriptions (or `settings.RabbitMq.ConnectionName` in your example).

[image]